# Unable to call a groovy closure

Tags: soap, groovy

I am using ws-lite to automate web service testing, and I want to have more flexible control over the xm l request generated.

Basically the request body is a groovy closure that will be passed to MarkupBuilder in order to create the SOAP message.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve (example taken from https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite):

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx')
def month = ["Feb"]

def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
    body {
        GetMothersDay('xmlns':'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
            year(2011)
            month.each{ a = null ->
                                        if (a != null){
                                            "month"(a)
                                        }
                                    }
        }
    }
}

assert "2011-05-08T00:00:00" == response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
assert 200 == response.httpResponse.statusCode
assert "ASP.NET" == response.httpResponse.headers['X-Powered-By']
```

The above example, I can create month tag fine with value/values specified.

But if I change it to be:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx')
def month_cl = { a -> "month"(a) }

def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
    body {
        GetMothersDay('xmlns':'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
            year(2011)
            month_cl("Feb")
        }
    }
}

assert "2011-05-08T00:00:00" == response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
assert 200 == response.httpResponse.statusCode
assert "ASP.NET" == response.httpResponse.headers['X-Powered-By']
```

I will have a missing method exception.

I don't quite understand why I can't just invoke a groovy closure like that?

Comment: What do you intend for the line `"month"(a)` to do exactly? That doesn't look valid.

Comment: yeah I know it does not look valid :(. I want it to do the same thing as the first request, to populate "Month":("Feb") element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate of `month_cl` closure has to be set to the current/parent delegate (in this case it is closure passed as param to `GetMothersDay`). Try with:

```
body {
    GetMothersDay('xmlns':'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
        year(2011)
        month_cl.delegate = delegate
        month_cl("Feb")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal to get `MissingMethodException`, because the closure `month_cl` is calling `month` method which does not exist. To do this (in your way), you should pass a `Closure c` to `month_cl` and call it on the argument `a`, like this:

```
def month_cl = { a, Closure c -> c(a) }
```

and using the new implementation, `month_cl("Feb")` becomes `month_cl("Feb") { "month" }` which results to `"month"("Feb")`.

Here is a working example:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx')
def months = ["Feb"]
def month_cl = { m, Closure c -> return c(m) }

def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
    body {
        GetMothersDay('xmlns':'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
            year(2011)
            month_cl("Feb") { "month" }  // -> month("Feb")
        }
    }
}

assert "2011-05-08T00:00:00" != response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
assert 200 == response.httpResponse.statusCode
assert "ASP.NET" == response.httpResponse.headers['X-Powered-By']
```